# Is there a ways to take out the artist and song from the array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose you have this type of array `(Sonny Rollins|Who Cares?|Sonny Rollins And Friends|Jazz|
Various|, Westminster Philharmonic Orchestra conducted by Kenneth Alwyn|Curse of the Werewolf: Prelude|Horror!|Soundtrack|1996)`. Is there any possible way to only take out Sonny Rollins and Who cares from the array?

Comment: Well it's separated by `|`, that should give you a hint. You can use `string.split("|", ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this array is a string array of x strings, you can create a substring from the index of the second instance of '|' to the end of the string.